# Help with reasoning about a component of the wikipedia proof for the ratio test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The proof I am referring to is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Proof.

I am currently attempting to reason about this proof by elaborating each step in detail and stating the assumptions explicitly. This is so that I gain a true understanding of the proof and the concept itself.

I do not understand the reasoning behind why it is logically consistent to bring $r = \dfrac{L + 1}{2}$ into the proof and then exclaim that $|a_{n+1}| < r|a_n|$. I am not disputing that $|a_{n+1}| < r|a_n|$. This is obvious, since $0 < r < L < 1$. However, It seems the $r$ just came out of no-where, with no justification at all. Of course, we can define some arbitrary value for $r$ and then state that $|a_{n+1}| < r|a_n|$ and have it be true. But this is just conjuring values out of no-where. Where did $r = \dfrac{L + 1}{2}$ even come from? There has to be some **connection**, some **link** between any value of $r$ that we bring into the proof and the ratio test itself, right? It doesn't make any sense to just start randomly bringing in arbitrary values. I understand that it is to show that $r$ is strictly between $L$ and $1$. However, that still does not explain how $r$ **fundamentally** came about.

We defined some $r$ and then exclaimed $|a_{n+1}| < r|a_n|$. **Why** did we define this $r$? **Why** did we multiply it by $|a_n|$? **What** was the logical mechanism, the **connection**, which told us to do this? **Fundamentally**, where did it come from? **How** is this logically consistent and **what** is the reasoning? I would greatly appreciate it if someone could take the time to clearly explain this.

I hope I have expressed my problem clearly enough for people to understand. I do apologise in advance if anyone finds it unclear. I find the problem both obsessively fascinating and insanely perplexing. All-in-all, I am basically asking for the reasoning behind why and how $r$ was conjured-up and used in such a way. If you require further clarification, please indicate so and I will act accordingly.

Thank you.

Comment: `This is obvious, since 0<r<L<1` I think you misread that part. In fact $r$ is the midpoint between $L$ and $1$ so in fact $0 \lt L \lt r = \frac{L+1}{2} \lt 1$. It is not essential to the proof that $r$ be the midpoint, they could have just as well chosen an arbitrary $r \in (L,1)$, but taking the midpoint is just a convenient choice.

Comment: Come on... $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} = L < 1$ means that you can find a geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$ with $r < 1$ such that $|a_n| < C r^n$ that's all.

Comment: @dxiv But why is there an $r$ in the first place? Where did the $r$ come from?

Comment: @user1952009 I don't understand how this answers my question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ThePointer Posted as an answer since it became too long for a comment.

Comment: Just as a meta-comment, I don't understand the downvote. On the contrary, this looks to me like a genuine and well articulated question. I would hope the downvoter cared to explain their reason.

Answer (score 1):

> This is obvious, since $0 \lt r \lt L \lt 1$

I think you misread that part. In fact $r$ is the midpoint between $L$ and $1$ 
 so actually $0 \lt L \lt r=\frac{L+1}{2} \lt 1$. It is not essential to the proof that $r$ be the midpoint, they could have just as well chosen an arbitrary $r \in (L,1)$, but taking the midpoint was just a convenient choice.

The intuition behind the ratio test is that since $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| \to L \lt 1$ the tail of the sequence can be bounded above by a geometric series with ratio $\lt 1$ which is known to converge. The rest is just formalizing that intuition. The ratio cannot be taken to be $L$ itself since it's not known that $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ tends to $L$ monotonically. But the convergence guarantees that for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ a tail of $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ for a certain $N$ and $\forall n \ge N$ will be inside $(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$. The wiki proof just chose $L+\epsilon = r = \frac{L+1}{2}$.

Comment: I am assuming that the ratio is $r$, right? So why are we multiplying $|a_n|$ by $r$? A geometric has every successive term multiplied by $r$, but for some reason here, it is multiplying only the first element, $|a_n|$ by $r$.

Comment: @ThePointer Mind the "*bounded above*" part. $a_n$ is *not* a geometric series, but (quoting from the wiki page) $|a_{n + i}|  < r^i |a_n |$ therefore $\sum_{i \ge 0} |a_{n+i}| \le |a_n| \sum_{i \ge 0} r^i = |a_n| \cdot \frac{1}{1-r}$.

Comment: Just to clarify, $r$ is the common ratio of the geometric series it alludes to?

Comment: Yes it is, indeed.

Comment: I think the pieces of the puzzle are starting to come together. Is it also true that the common ratio of any convergent geometric series (in this case, $r$) multiplied by any other term (in this case, $|a_n|$) is also convergent? For instance, we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^n\dfrac{1}{81}$ is convergent, since the common ratio $\left(\dfrac{1}{6} \right)^n$ has an abs. value $< 1$. We also know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n}$ (the harmonic series) is divergent. However, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^n  \dfrac{1}{n}$ is convergent ($|r|$ < 1)

Comment: Sorry, not sure I completely follow the "*multiplied by any other term*" part. It's certainly the case that some divergent series (like, for the most trivial example, $\sum r^{-n}$ with $r \lt 1$) remain divergent when multiplied term-by-term with $\sum r^n$. But if you mean that $\sum \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^n \frac{1}{n}$ can be proved convergent by the ratio test then, yes, that's correct.

Comment: The wiki proof says 'We can then show that the series converges absolutely by showing that its terms will eventually become less than those of a certain convergent geometric series.'. This is also what you alluded to. I don't understand why this would prove convergence, though? My thought was, we have $|a_{n + i}|  < r^i |a_n |$. We also know that the original series must have been $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ Therefore, the proof is trying to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(r^i)a_n$, where $r$ is equal to the the common ratio of a convergent geometric series, must be convergent.

Comment: The ratio test *proves* that $\sum_{i \ge 0} |a_{n+i}| \le |a_n| \cdot \frac{1}{1-r}$ converges, which implies that $\sum_{n \ge 1} |a_n|$ converges which in turn implies that the original series [converges absolutely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence). Sorry, don't know how to put that any more clearly, and I am not sure what precisely your difficulty is with at this point.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand it now. We know that $0 \lt L \lt r=\frac{L+1}{2} \lt 1$, where $r$ is the common ratio of some convergent geometric series. We also know that $|a_{n+i}| < r^i|a_n|$. Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n+i}| < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^i|a_n|$, where $|r^i| < 1$. Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^i|a_n|$ must be absolutely convergent. This implies that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n+i}| < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^i|a_n| =$ absolutely convergent. Therefore, since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n+i}|$ is bounded from above, it must also be absolutely convergent.